# How to make whole android screen (current) unresponsive while processing?

Tags: android, user-interface, block

I have one activity, which contains header (title bar). This header also contains the image of Sync feature of my app.
As per requirement of client, I want that when the user tap on this button, the animation of this image (button) starts, which is rotating animation (I've achieved this animation). But while this animation is being performed, I want to freeze the whole screen so the user can not tap on other views while sync is in progress.
Till now I've used the following method but with no success :

```
private boolean stopUserInteractions = false;
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(int i) {
    View v = imgSync;
    if (v.getId() == R.list.imgSync) {
        System.out.println("UI Blocked...");
        return false;
        } 
    else {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        return false;
}
```

Can anyone guide me for this? Any trick/snippet or any other hint.
**EDIT** : I dont want to use ProgressDialog while this sync process is being happening.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like horrible UX. I want to break my phone in half every time it locks up.

Comment: That sounds like a truly terrible idea. You should work in order to never have a blocked UI, not the opposite.

Comment: @Teovald : You are right, but I am also notifying user that progress is in progress by the means of image animation, contained in my screen's header. So user won't be confused about whether something has gone wrong or not..

Answer (score 1):

Have an OnTouchListener class within your activity, or let your Activity implement OnTouchListener. All children of the activity's layout should set a single object of this if they want to listen touch events. Within listener, check whether you should process the click or not.

Comment: Can you post little code snippets depicting the above scenario?